# RTL direction after element changes position depending on language used

Tags: css, right-to-left

I have two style sheets, a ltr and an rtl version. Take the following snippet

```
 @if $text-direction == 'ltr' {
  .arrow-link:before {
    content: "\e021";
    font-family: 'iconfont';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }    

}@else {
    .arrow-link:after {
    content: "\e023";
    font-family: 'iconfont';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;       
    }
}
```

This works as expected using english. But If i swap for hebrew text the icon is palced ont he wrong side and Im not sure why.  This fiddle explains better, the last span with hebrew text places the after element before.

https://jsfiddle.net/2zze9q8z/

Comment: wouldn't still be the `:after` pseudo element in the else block?

Comment: This sort of makes sense - the icon is placed **after** the text in all the examples. In English after the "o" and in Arabic (it's not Hebrew by the way) it's also displayed after the last letter.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. My brain doensn't work properly when doing anything involving rtl